# how can I create opends attribute to insert new data about employee

Tags: php, ubuntu, opends

How can I create opends directory new attribute to insert new data about employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a LDIF with the attribute type, add to dn: cn=schema using ldapmodify.

For details, please read this: https://www2.opends.org/wiki/page/HowToExtendTheLDAPSchema